# Difference of two powers where a term is multiplied by some constant

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients

We know that the difference of two powers $x^n-y^n$ over its linear factor $x-y$ is

$$\frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(x^{n-j-1}y^{j}),$$

where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and all $x,y\in\mathbb{F}, \ \mathbb{F}$ being one of the standard number systems (i.e. $\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\text{and} \ \mathbb{C}$).

I was wondering if there is a similar theorem for when one of the terms is multiplied by some constant $a$. Is there a theorem that states $ax^n-y^n$ over $ax-y$ is equal to some summation along the lines of

$$ax^n-y^n=(ax-y)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}???$$

I have tried figuring this out myself, but I have no formal training in mathematics beyond a high school level and am only in the beginning stages of learning number theory.

Without knowing a better route to take, I attempted to get the first few terms of the summation by long division:

$$\frac{ax^n-y^n}{ax-y}=x^{n-1}+\frac{x^{n-2}y}{a}+\frac{x^{n-3}y^2}{a^2}+\ .\ .\ .\ $$

from which I wrote a summation that seems to match:

$$\frac{ax^n-y^n}{ax-y}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^{n-j-1}y^{j}}{a^{j}}.$$

However, I am unable to prove this statement to be true or false.

Answer (score 2):

$$ax^n-y^n=(ax-y)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}???$$

If such identity holds, then when $y=ax$, the expression vanishes.

That is we would require $$ax^n-(ax)^n=0$$

and we have $$a=a^n$$

This can't hold true for all the $a$.

We can however view $ax^n-y^n=(a^\frac1n x)^n -y^n$.